# Android How to change TimePicker theme?

Tags: android, themes, customization, android-theme, timepicker

Currently using Theme.Sherlock theme for my application. Is that possible to change theme for TimePicker widget. I want to change the blue divider to green, and the white text to black.

I did not found anything usable yet (unfortunately TimePicker is missing from android-holo-colors.com tool), hope you have a good idea.

Thank you!

Comment: Tumbleweed post or what? I'd also like to know if this is possible.

Answer (score 0):

Since Android SDK did not allow you to modify elements inside timepicker. You need a way to do sort of hacking.
For the Text Colour, you need to change the theme.Here is a little example in my Fragment.
the focus is on the "R.style.Picker_Black", i set the theme to "Theme.Holo.Light" in order to show "Black" text colour in the timepicker.

```
  @Override
  public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    final Context contextThemeWrapper = new ContextThemeWrapper(getActivity(), R.style.Picker_Black);
    LayoutInflater localInflater = inflater.cloneInContext(contextThemeWrapper);
    View v = localInflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_booking, container, false);
    return v;
  }
```

Define style in "style.xml"

```
  <style name="Picker.Black" parent="android:Theme.Holo.Light">
    <item name="android:editTextStyle">@style/Widget.EditText.White</item>
  </style>
```

For Divider:

```
public class CustomTimePicker extends TimePicker {
  public CustomTimePicker(Context context) {
    super(context);
    init();
  }

  public CustomTimePicker(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
    super(context, attrs);
    init();
  }

  public CustomTimePicker(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle) {
    super(context, attrs, defStyle);
    init();
  }

  private void init() {
    removeAllDividers(this);
  }

  private void removeAllDividers(ViewGroup picker) {
    for (int i = 0; i < picker.getChildCount(); i++) {
      View view = picker.getChildAt(i);
      if (view instanceof NumberPicker) {
        try {
          Field field = NumberPicker.class.getDeclaredField("mSelectionDivider");
          field.setAccessible(true);
          field.set(view, null);
        } catch (Exception e) {
        }
      } else if (view instanceof ViewGroup) {
        removeAllDividers((ViewGroup) view);
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Although I am a bit late for this answer but for those who will wonder in future. Add in `gradle`:

```
compile 'com.github.rey5137:material:1.2.2'
```

This is the [best library](https://github.com/rey5137/material/wiki) I have ever seen. Use it. It contains every information you need.